# Observing items being added to a list in RX

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I am trying to get a simple demo working.

I have a collection of strings and I want to watch it for additions, without using any control event code. Somehow I've gotten the impression, perhaps wrongly, that Rx or another part of .Net supports this, without resorting to wiring up all the various events that (may or may not) add members to the collection.

If I replace my `source` with an interval, as in the commented out code, the delegate gets called (ala, `var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`. This gives me hope I can do what I want to here, perhaps falsely.

The basic example came from [Creating and Subscribing to Simple Observable Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx)

In the code below, what I want to do is observe the `source` collection directly (not through control events) and call a delegate when an item is added to the collection.

I would prefer not to bypass LINQ or RX if they do, indeed, support my thesis that they support this functionality.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading;

public class frmRx
{

    ObservableCollection<string> ObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Dim source = Observable.ToObservable(ObservableCollection).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)

    //this code worked, but it's not a collection I made
    //source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(x => x.ToString).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);

    private void frmRx_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        IConnectableObservable<string> Publication = Observable.Publish<string>(source);
        Publication.Subscribe(x => { AddToTreeView(x); }, ex => { }, () => { });
        Publication.Connect();
    }

    private void AddToTreeView(string Text)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Text); //this never gets called
    }

    // this is just my test way of adding a member to the collection.
    // but the adding could happen anywhere,
    // and I want to watch the collection changes regardless of how it came about
    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection.Add(TextBox1.Text.Last);
    }
    public frmRx()
    {
        Load += frmRx_Load;
       TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly to answer your 'rant'. The examples aren't convoluted. They always begin simple and then work up to more complex examples. It seems like you are ACTUALLY complaining, why is Rx.net so complicated. The simple reason. Because it is dealing with a very complex concept, time. Namely Rx, deals with multiple dimensions of time simultaneously. For example, a common Rx "query" is, "Watch what the user is typing, when he stops typing for 500ms, then send off a request, which we will wait for 3seconds for, unless the user starts typing again, during the request time, in which case, cancel."

Comment: It isn't clear what you want the `ObservableCollection` for. The sad truth of the issue is that `ObservableCollection` despite the name has nothing to do with Rx.net.

Comment: Your question asks "how to make simple sub/pub work" but you don't ever say what you are subscribing/publishing. Your code makes not attempt to convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Aron, see the commented out code. I was trying to have a list of strings and have a delegate fire if an item was added to that collection. I want to observe the collection, as per the title. Maybe you can undo your close vote now? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is wrong. If it was readable it would be right. You are still missing lots of information. With fix my code questions you need to have, what the code should do in words, or pseudo code. Also, fix the question, not comment.

Comment: @Aron, ok see my edit. If you can help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an Rx.net framework, like ReactiveUI. I shall show you how that would work.

```
ReactiveList<string> _collection = new ReactiveList<string>();

public Constructor()
{
     var subscription = _collection.ItemsAdded.Subject(added => doSomething(added));
     this.Disposed += (o, e) => subscription.Dispose();
}
```

Here how much code you need to get this to "work" without third party. Also, this code has NO exception handling in it at all.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _source = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //There will be issues with the exception handling
        Observable.FromEventPattern
            <NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>
            (x => _source.CollectionChanged += x, x => _source.CollectionChanged -= x)
            .Where(x => x.EventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            .SelectMany(x => x.EventArgs.NewItems.Cast<string>())
            .Subscribe(AddToTreeView);

    }

    public void AddToTreeView(string text)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great Aron. Is there any example of what this very thing would take without a 3rd party framework? Because my boss is 3rd party averse, is why I ask. Thanks much. Also, see I clarified my question even further.

Comment: 3rd party libraries require an additional approval process, both with the boss and the other team members.  I see your edit  and thanks for that.

Answer (score 10):

You are making the mistake that `Observable.ToObservable(ObservableCollection)` will create an `IObservable<string>` that will produce values for future updates of the `ObservableCollection`.

It does not.

The `.ToObservable(...)` extension method simply turns an `IEnumerable<>` into and `IObservable<>` such that the values are enumerated at the moment in time that the observable is subscribed to.

You need to use a `Subject<string>` if you want new values pushed to your subscribers.

Further to this, your code isn't as simple as possible. Why are you mucking around with the publishing of observables?

Here's the simplest code you could write to get this to work:

```
public class frmRx
{
    private Subject<string> source = new Subject<string>();

    public frmRx()
    {
        source.ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(x => TreeView1.Nodes.Add(x));
        TextBox1.TextChanged += (s, e) => source.OnNext(TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

I've included the `.ObserveOn(this)` as it is a good habit to put them in but it shouldn't be needed in this case.

What I would prefer to see is this though:

```
public class frmRx
{
    public frmRx()
    {
        Observable
            .FromEventPattern(
                h => textBox1.TextChanged += h,
                h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h)
            .Select(x => textBox1.Text)
            .Subscribe(x => treeView1.Nodes.Add(x));
    }
}
```

This avoids subjects and it is as simple as it can get while being strongly-typed.

It would even be better to go one step further and do a better job of cleaning up your subscription on closing, like this:

```
        var subscription =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(
                    h => textBox1.TextChanged += h,
                    h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h)
                .Select(x => textBox1.Text)
                .Subscribe(x => treeView1.Nodes.Add(x));

        this.FormClosing += (s, e) => subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To a newbie like me, this seems like a very convoluted way of simply watching the textbox TextChanged and adding an item to the TreeView. What I really want to do is, watch the collection directly and fire an delegate when an item is added (by any means). Can you show me that? That's what I really want to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @toddmo - for that you should write your own class that implements `IList<T>` that wraps the normal `List<T>`. You can then intercept all of the method calls and send values out for the `Add` method. One question though, do you not also need to know when values are modified and/or removed?

Comment: @toddmo - I wouldn't call this "convoluted", let alone "very convoluted". Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm sorry if that was offensive, I didn't mean to be. I don't undersand yet, in my learning of Rx, the difference between your last example, and simply handling the event raised by the `TextBox` when it changes, to call `AddToTreeView`.

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate some of the "drudge work" of wiring up events by having my framework provide a higher level of service to me. By using Aron's second example, I can watch collections where I don't have the source code, and without a wrapper, correct? I do have a base collection which is  based on `List<T>`. If I base it on `ObservableCollection<T>` that would be an upgrade, right? Since it gives me this watching capability?

Comment: @toddmo - Rx is more overhead for simple tasks, but it very quickly becomes much easier when you want to do anything more complicated. The initial overhead becomes very worthwhile quickly.